# A contradiction to a proof by Chern & Lashof?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870275) it is proved that

> Any local diffeomorphism from a compact connected $n$-dimensional manifold ($n>1$) to the sphere is a diffeomorphism.

This result seems to contradict the proof of Theorem 1 in [a classical paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2372684.pdf) by Chern and Lashof, as explained below.

Let $M$ be a compact $n$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+N}$. Let $B_{\nu}$ denote the unit normal bundle of $M$, whose fiber at $p \in M$ is the $(N-1)$-sphere inside the normal space of $M$ at $p$. The authors define a map $\overline{\nu}$ which simply translates any unit normal vector of $M$ to the unit sphere centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n+N}$ :
$$\begin{align}
B_{\nu} &\to S^{n+N-1}_{0}\\
(p,\nu) &\mapsto \nu \,.
\end{align}
$$

In the proof of Theorem 1 (p. 312, first paragraph) they show that

> Every point of $S^{n+N-1}_{0}$ is covered at least twice by $\overline{\nu}$.

Now, if $\overline{\nu}$ is a local diffeomorphism, $N>1$, and $M$ is connected, then the map $\overline{\nu}$ satisfies the conditions of the statement above (as the unit normal bundle is compact and connected in such case). Being a diffeomorphism, it cannot cover more than once the sphere.

What am I missing?

EDIT (in view of the comments): I am not claiming that the map $\overline{\nu}$ is always a local diffeomorphism, only that there are cases where it is.

Comment: I don't see why that map is a local diffeomorphism (in fact, Chern and Lashof mention its critical points).

Comment: @Stephen That map is not, in general, a local diffeomorphism. The problem is that it could be, and in such case their conclusion would not hold.

Comment: Think about the case of a hypersurface first (so we don't need to worry about the normal bundle or Lipschitz-Killing curvature). Only when $K>0$ everywhere is the map everywhere a local diffeomorphism.  And, then, of course, this happens only when $M$ is diffeomorphic to a sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree with you. In the case of hypersurfaces, however, the unit normal bundle is not connected, so the result of the linked question does not apply (and so no contradiction is present).

Comment: "The problem is that it could be..." I don't see why that should be so. In fact, Chern and Lashof's argument, together with the answer you link, seems to me to be establishing that it is not. I don't see any problem with the argument that $\tilde{\nu}$ covers each point at least twice.